# Word (or phrase) to describe someone who leaves out important pieces of information

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase to describe a person, or at least the quality of a person, who tends to leave out important details when communicating? For example someone said "The store Costco is dangerous". Initially I thought he meant their have been a lot of violent crimes around Costco, but latter I found out he was trying to say Costco is so cheap you end up spending a lot of money on things you don't really need.

I would like to use the word in the sentence "Person x is very _____ " or "Person x is very _____ in his communication style".

I was thinking of the word "unclear" but often times a person is unclear for the exact opposite reason, because they add too much information.

Comment: Unreliable narrator?

Comment: @randal'thor that's more of a literary term, not one you'd describe any actual person with .

Comment: @Celeritas laconic; terse; frugal with their words; evasive?

Comment: "Politician" comes to mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase [being] **economical with the truth** can have this meaning:

> avoiding ​stating the ​true ​facts about a ​situation, or ​lying
>   about it

{[Cambridge Dictionaries online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/economical-with-the-truth)}

But **dissimulation** is a better fit

> dissimulation (misleading by withholding pertinent information) {[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economical_with_the_truth)}

I'd avoid the agent noun (dissimulator), which has other connotations (at least) to do with one's beliefs etc, and sounds almost outlandish in any case.

Another term is **elliptical**:

> elliptic or elliptical adj.
>
> 3. a. Of or relating to extreme economy of oral or written expression.
>
> b. Marked by deliberate obscurity of style or expression.

{[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elliptical)} and

> 3. (Literary & Literary Critical Terms) (of speech, literary style, etc) a. very condensed or concise, often so as to be obscure or
>      ambiguous

{Collins; same link}

Comment: Economical with truth, I like that phrase.

Comment: This is very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

"Conservative with giving details"

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using "[***double-speak***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/doublespeak)" as in "Paxon always uses doublespeak" and it means:

> language that is intended to make people believe something which is
>   not true, or that 
>   ***can be understood in two different ways***

or

> deliberately euphemistic, ambiguous, or obscure language:

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

"Doubletalk" is a synonym which means:

> inflated, involved, and often ***deliberately ambiguous language***.

[Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score 0):

"The person is ______________ in his communicative style."

- *black-or-white*
- *simplistic*
- *simple-minded*
- *not very nuanced*